# alternative solution to binary search just as good?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, search, binary-search

for a binary search questions I came up with the following solution:

```
function binarySearch(arr,numba){
    
    var left = 0
    var right = arr.length - 1
    
    while (left <= right){
        let middle = Math.floor((left+right)/2)
        if (arr[middle] < numba){
            left ++;
            
        }
        else if (numba < arr[middle]){
            right -- ;
            
        }
        else if (numba === arr[middle]){
            return middle
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

but the suggested solution is :

```
function binarySearc(arr, elem) {
    var start = 0;
    var end = arr.length - 1;
    var middle = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
    while(arr[middle] !== elem && start <= end) {
        if(elem < arr[middle]){
            end = middle - 1;
        } else {
            start = middle + 1;
        }
        middle = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
    }
    if(arr[middle] === elem){
        return middle;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Is the second solution better than what I have in any way or are they essentially the same thing?

Comment: Looks basically the same to me although yours seems cleaner and easier to reason about, less repeated code. Some folks get big on the "single return statement" thing and need to break out of loops and do double conditions to satisfy their hunger for always only having one return statement at all costs.

Comment: Print the `left` and `right` values in your code, and `start` and `end` in the other code, and the difference should be obvious: your code is *not* a binary search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the second solution is better. It's the only one that's actually performing a binary search (computational complexity of `O(log n)`). See below snippet to see how many times the `middle` needs to be recalculated using the suggested solution:

```js
function binarySearc(arr, elem) {
    var start = 0;
    var end = arr.length - 1;
    var middle = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
    let iterCount = 0;
    while(arr[middle] !== elem && start <= end) {
        iterCount++;
        if(elem < arr[middle]){
            end = middle - 1;
        } else {
            start = middle + 1;
        }
        middle = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
    }
    console.log('iterCount', iterCount);
    if(arr[middle] === elem){
        return middle;
    }
    return -1;
}

const arr = Array.from({ length: 100 }, (_, i) => i);
binarySearc(arr, 30);
```

In contrast, your solution requires reassigning `middle` on the order of `O(n)` times - it's not actually doing a binary search.

```js
function binarySearch(arr,numba){
    
    var left = 0
    var right = arr.length - 1
    
    let iterCount = 0;
    while (left <= right){
        iterCount++;
        let middle = Math.floor((left+right)/2)
        console.log(middle);
        if (arr[middle] < numba){
            left ++;
            
        }
        else if (numba < arr[middle]){
            right -- ;
            
        }
        else if (numba === arr[middle]){
            console.log('iterCount', iterCount);
            return middle
        }
    }
    return -1
}

const arr = Array.from({ length: 100 }, (_, i) => i);
binarySearch(arr, 30);
```

For example, with an array of length 100, you start with `left` of 0 and `right` of 99, and then on each iteration inside the loop, you either increment left by 1 or decrement right by 1. True binary search would involve incrementing or decrementing to cut down the remaining elements to be searched by about half - for example, to start at 0-99, then go to 0-49, then 24-49, then 24-36, and so on. That way you get to the target (if it exists) much faster than 0-99, then 0-98, then 0-97, etc.